# Coordinating destructors on two classes, where one class needs to clean up first

Tags: c++, oop, destructor

Let's say I create a `CDatabase` and a `CStatement` class. The `CStatement` class relies on the `CDatabase` class for some of its handles.

```
class CDatabase
{
public:
    SQLHENV m_hEnv;
    SQLHDBC m_hDBC;

    CDatabase()
    {
    }

    ~CDatabase()
    {
        FreeHandles();
    }

    void FreeHandles()
    {
        // ...
    }
}

class CStatement
{
public:
    SQLHSTMT m_hStmt;
    CDatabase* m_pDatabase;

    CStatement(CDatabase* pDatabase)
    {
        m_pDatabase = pDatabase;
    }

    ~CStatement()
    {
        FreeHandles();
    }

    void FreeHandles()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

It's important that `CStatement` frees its handles before `CDatabase` does.

The issue is if both objects are declared local in a method, as they will be, there is some question about which object will get it's destructor called first.

One idea I had is to have `CStatement` call a `RegisterStatement` method in `CDatabase`. This way, if the `CDatabase` destructor gets called first, it can call a method in any `CStatement` objects depending on it to before free its own handles. I could also add an `UnregisterStatement` that `CStatement` could call from it's destructor so `CDatabase` would know not to call that one if it was destroyed first.

But calling the `UnregisterStatement` method is iffy because maybe the `CDatabase` class has already been destroyed.

Does anyone know of a solid way to approach this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both are declared local in a function, then `CDatabase` would necessarily be declared first, since `CStatement` takes it in constructor. Therefore, it'll be destroyed last. Objects with automatic duration are always destroyed in reverse order of construction.

Comment: Note that another solution here might be for `CStatement` to take and store a `std::shared_ptr<CDatabase>`. Now the `CDatabase` is never destructed before the `CStatement`. Also solves the lifetime issue of `CStatement`s holding unowned pointers.